# IE is not calling a function in onblur event

Tags: javascript, php, html, c, internet-explorer

Here's the thing: I've removed the content of my JavaScript function for tests and now it looks just like this:

```
function media(id) {
    alert('IT WORKS!');
}
```

I'm calling this function in two diferent events. The first one is the "onload" event and the second one is the "onblur" event:

```
<body onload="media()">

<!-- irrelevant part of the code -->

<input type="text" readonly onBlur="if (teto(this, 100, 1)) { salva_campo('EDICAO[ALUNO_DISC][1][NOTA][0][DADOS][VALOR]', 'SALVA_NOTA', '43782', '5045', this.value); media(1); } " name="EDICAO[ALUNO_DISC][1][NOTA][0][DADOS][VALOR]" id="EDICAO[ALUNO_DISC][1][NOTA][0][DADOS][VALOR]" size="5" value="" tabindex="2" maxlength="5" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) muda_campo(1, 0);">
```

The code works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE the function media() is just being called by onload event. I think the problem has nothing to do with the onblur event, because the function salva_campo() works well. Any ideas about what's happening?

Comment: The first thing you should do is open IE's JavaScript console and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

The blur event does fire in Internet Explorer, you can [view the following simple test on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r883xj43/):

```
<input type="text" readonly onBlur="alert('blur');">
```

This means the error is likely in the script you are running. You haven't supplied all of your code so it cannot be tested, but if you hit F12 in Internet Explorer and look at the Console tab, you should be given a more descriptive error, which you can ask us about.

Comment: I've tried the onBlur="alert('blur');" and it works, but calling this especific function media() does not. I'm using IE7, so I don't think the F12 is an option. The code has too many lines, but I'll try to give more information.

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied the function content and defined with another name. One I've called in the onload event and the other I've called in the onblur event. I don't know if IE7 does not support the same function being called by different events with different arguments, but now my code is working.